# making generated column optional in NestJS/TypeORM

Tags: javascript, database, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I have a scenario in which I have to make `generated` column `optional`. actually we have to generate the field if it is not present.

```
@ApiProperty()
@Generated('rowid')  //this is generating value automatically
@Column({name:"certificate_no",type: 'varchar'})
certificateNo?: string;
```

actually in UI we have a functionality in which we have to `duplicate` the row. so when API gets called and `certificateNo` is not present then this value should be `generated`. if it is present then `present value should be inserted into database`.

I am putting in `DTO`.

```
@ApiProperty()
@IsOptional()
@IsString()
certificateNo?: string;
```

Actually it is generating `certificateNo` everytime even if it is present. is there anyway to handle this scenario?

[image]

if user clicks on `+` button same row should be duplicated.

any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create primary key separately.

```
export class Certificate extends BaseEntity {
    @ApiProperty()
    @Generated('rowid')
    @Column({ name: 'certificate_no', type: 'varchar' })
    certificateNo: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ name: 'request_status', type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
    requestStatus: RequestStatus;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ name: 'sponsor', type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
    sponsor: string;
```

and you can extend `BaseEntity` like above. in BaseEntity your primary key will be generated. send the field when you recreate the record..only that field will be stored. means dont make this field as primary key.